# If a function $F$ is defined as $F(x)=F(2x/3) + 1$, where $F(1) = 1$, how can I define the function non-recursively?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

> If a recursive function $F$ is defined as $F(x)=F(2x/3) + 1$, where $F(1) = 1$, how can one define the function non-recursively?

For example, $$F(1.5)=F(3/2)=F\left(\frac{2\cdot(3/2)}3\right)+1=F(1)+1=2$$How can I find the non-recursive version of this function?

Comment: What about x=0? then 0=1?

Comment: There are bazillions of such functions—indeed, you can choose the values of $F(x)$ completely arbitrarily for $1<x<\frac32$ (and, depending on the intended domain, $x=0$ and $-\frac32<x\le-1$) and then extend it using the given functional equation.

Comment: Try looking at the function $G(x) = F( (3/2)^x)$

Comment: @DanielV I can see that G(x) = x + 1 but how does that help me get F(x)?

Comment: Please use mathjax.

Comment: @ElanSK If $G(x) = F((3/2)^x)$, then $F(y) = G(....)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=2/3$. Thus $F(x)=F(ax)+1$. As was mentioned in the comments, if one defines $$G(x)=F\left(a^x\right),$$
then $$G(x)=F(a^{x+1})+1=G(x+1)+1.$$
Then, upon differentiation, we have that $$G'(x)=G'(x+1),\qquad G(0)=1.$$
This differential equation has a lot of solutions. Perhaps the simplest is of the form $G(x)=\alpha x+\beta$. Suppose this is the case. Then $$\alpha x+\beta=1+\beta+\alpha(x+1)\Rightarrow \alpha=-1\\ G(0)=1\Rightarrow \beta=1.$$
Thus we may write $G(x)=1-x$ as a solution. Indeed, this satisfies the differential equation. Anyway, if $y=\log_ax$, then $G(y)=F(a^y)=F(x)$. Therefore we can write
$$F(x)=1-\log_{2/3}x.$$